# how to integrate converse js XMPP with react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xmpp, integration, converse.js

I want to implement a chat client. so I tried with conversejs. but I can't found to integrate it with the react application. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://cdn.conversejs.org/7.0.2/dist/converse.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.conversejs.org/7.0.2/dist/converse.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
  <script>
    converse.initialize({
        authentication: 'anonymous',
        auto_login: true,
        auto_join_rooms: [
            'anonymous@conference.nomnom.im',
        ],
        bosh_service_url: 'https://conversejs.org/http-bind/', // Please use this connection manager only for testing purposes
        jid: 'nomnom.im', // XMPP server which allows anonymous login (doesn't
                          // allow chatting with other XMPP servers).
        notify_all_room_messages: [
            'anonymous@conference.nomnom.im',
        ],
        singleton: true,
        show_controlbox_by_default: true,
        view_mode: 'overlayed'
    });
</script>
</html>
```